# How to make eclipse cdt(c++) build&run in one button?

Tags: c++, build, compilation, eclipse-cdt

I code in c++ using eclipse cdt.

Every time i make changes i have to press this combination:

- ctrl+s - save(without saving, just hitting the run button runs the
  old version of code)
- build(hammer button)
- run

**I remember i could just hit the run button - and it would do all 3 steps - save, build,run**

How to make the run button achieve and do all this work?

Comment: Is there an option Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Save automatically before build?

Answer (score 1):

This is configurable in the "Run Configurations" settings.

1. From the toolbar, go to Run -> Run Configurations...
2. Select your run configuration on the left
3. On the "Main" tab on the right, look for "Build (if required) before launching"